# Linked list, an element gets lost

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm trying to insert a node to the end of the linked list and everything works like wonder, however, when it comes to last element it prints `null`. There problem must be in the `else` block, I was thinking that when I look for the last item it may points to `NULL` instead to the element that have `next` as `NULL`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


#define HOW_MANY 7
char *names[HOW_MANY]= {"Simon", "Suzie", "Alfred", "Chip", "John", "Tim",
              "Harriet"};
int ages[HOW_MANY]= {22, 24, 106, 6, 18, 32, 24};

struct person {
  int age;
  char *name;
    struct person *next;
};


struct person* insert_end(struct person *ptr, char *name, int age)
{
  //The new location for the new person
  struct person* newPer = malloc(sizeof(struct person));
    if (newPer == NULL) {
        printf("something went wrong allocating the memory\n");
        exit(1);
    }

  newPer -> name = name;
  newPer -> age = age;
  //Make its next points previous element
  if (ptr->next == NULL) {
    newPer -> next = ptr;


    return newPer;
  }
  else {
    struct person *tmp = ptr;
    while(tmp -> next != NULL){
      tmp = tmp -> next;

    }
    printf("%s", tmp -> name);
    tmp -> next = newPer;


    //if(strcmp("Harriet",name)==0)
    return ptr;
  }
  //return the new address so that it becomes the new HEAD of the linked list
    return newPer;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    //This is the head of the list
    struct person *HEAD = NULL;
    HEAD = malloc(sizeof(struct person));
    if (HEAD == NULL) {
        printf("something went wrong allocating the memory");
        exit(1);
    }


    int i;
  //insert a new person and make HEAD points to it, so that HEADS
  //will be pointing to the last element added to the linked list.
  for (i = 0; i < HOW_MANY; i++){
        HEAD = insert_end (HEAD, names[i], ages[i]);
    }

  struct person* tmp = HEAD;
  //We can use the member name(pointer) as the condition, if we did then extra
  //unwanted elements added to the linked list by accident won't be printed
  while (tmp != NULL){
    if (tmp -> next != NULL)
      printf("The name is %s, the age is %d years\n", tmp->name, tmp->age);

    //store the pointer in a tmp so than we can access the next pointer then
    //free tmp
    struct person* prevtmp = tmp;
    tmp = tmp -> next;
    free(prevtmp);
  }
}
```

The output is

```
The name is Simon, the age is 22 years
The name is (null), the age is 0 years
The name is Suzie, the age is 24 years
The name is Alfred, the age is 106 years
The name is Chip, the age is 6 years
The name is John, the age is 18 years
The name is Tim, the age is 32 years
```

Comment: what is this code even supposed to do in the last bit? just print out the list?

Comment: Your first ever allocated element (top of `main`) never gets a `name`.

Comment: The last bit is just to print everything out

Comment: Your malloc was not compiling on my side, remember to cast your malloc once your memory is allocated, like that `(struct person*) malloc(sizeof(struct person));`

Comment: When I compiler you code, I get 'Unhandled exception at 0x00E74566 in StackOverFlow.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCDCDCDD5.' when I compile on VS2013 and run it.

Answer (score 1):

Simply change `if (tmp -> next != NULL)` to `if (tmp != NULL)`. You forgot that the last node in the list will not have a "next" node.

Comment: This seems to work but it prints the null line as well. So if I had a pointer to a structure without initialising the structure wouldn't that means that its members are NULL?

Comment: @Zed No it does not, you would also need to initialize it to NULL as others have pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `newPer->next` is set to `NULL`.

```
  newPer -> name = name;
  newPer -> age = age;
  newPer -> next = NULL;
```

Same for your sentinel `HEAD`.

```
    HEAD = malloc(sizeof(struct person));
    if (HEAD == NULL) {
         printf("something went wrong allocating the memory");
        exit(1);
    }
    HEAD->name = "HEAD";
    HEAD->age = -1;
    HEAD->next = NULL;
```

Comment: Same for HEAD in the main function.

Comment: @Zed can consider making `Simon` the head, then start your filling loop at 1

Comment: Won't that means that I have a different root, instead of having the root as a valid structure but it points to a NULL pointer?

Comment: @Zed: I am simply maintaining your own structure. Your code is moving `HEAD` around to point at the new node. I assumed that was intentional.

Answer (score 0):

You initialize `*HEAD` as `NULL`, but you never populate that address with a person, so that `NULL` gets pushed to the end and stays there. Try adding this at the top of your function:

```
if (*ptr == NULL){
    newPer = ptr
}
else {
    struct person* newPer = malloc(sizeof(struct person));
    if (newPer == NULL) {
        printf("something went wrong allocating the memory\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

You might have to change a couple of other conditions, but the idea is that you need to check if newPer is the first entry in the list, and change how you handle that case.

Comment: Since NULL is considered a pointer value i'm not allowed to compare a struct to a pointer

Comment: @Zed, newPer in the example above is a pointer, you can always compare NULL to any pointer.

Answer (score 0):

First off, an uninitialized list head should always be NULL.  The insert functions should detect this and simply return the properly initialized first node.  After that, you can base your logic on whether `p->next` is `NULL`.  You pretty much have to rewrite a good bit of your code to get it right.  For 'insert_end' should always return the head pointer it was handed, 'insert_front' should always return the new node because it is always the new head.

Comment: I think I have the head as NULL, I don't understand the 2nd part where the function should detect this. For the return pointer I did what you said. Can you clarify the 2nd part?

Comment: In 'main' you initialize the first node by calling 'malloc'.  All of your list management should be done in your list management functions.  It's called separation of concerns.  In your case, 'main' is just a test driver for you list implementation (homework assignment?), it should not take part in list management beyond keeping the head pointer your other functions return to it.